# EXCEL How do I summarize a list?

Tags: excel-formula

I am going to do my best to explain what I have and what I need.

I have a list of wood pieces (length x width) that I want to summaries in order to have the pieces quantity of every type of piece.

For example

This list has 3 columns (Colum A Colum B and Colum C)

Colum A shows the length

Colum B shows the width

Colum C shows the quantity

And in the list, the same type of piece can be shown few times and whit different quantities.

Looks like this

10x10 1

10x10 4

20x40 6

30x40 1

30x40 5

20x40 3

I’m looking for a solution that can help me to:

SUM the quantity shown in Colum C for the same type of wood piece.

The solution for this example is next.

10x10 5

20x40 9

30x40 6

clik for the example image [EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jC7Oq.png)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Elaborate it please, with example.

Comment: [How do I ask a **good** question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I think this is one of the worst questions asked here: no content besides a link to an image, everything in caps (why are you yelling to us dude?). Please edit the question and let us know what exactly you need, what you tried, and where did you get stuck.

Comment: I do apologize for the inconvenience Steffen  Harbrich and Cristik last night I spent hours looking for a solution for this and I couldn’t find it. I have to say I’m not an Ecxel expert AT ALL and I have no experience At All in this type of forums. I’m just a regular guy looking for  a Solution whit you guys. Thanks for the help and please let me know if I was clear and if you could see the image I have uploaded.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/jC7Oq.png

Comment: If you have any idea of how I can improve the question of this post please let me know so I can change it and it can be helpful for other people whit the same problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the SUMIFS formula (see image).  First you'll need to manually enter all different combinations of length and width (see columns E and F).

[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GQRb.png)

Comment: Hi Sly. Thanks a lot for your time and help. It does work indeed. Your example is very clear and even the need of the combinations to be entered, it help me a lot. The example I have shown its very simple, but the real list is much more complicated and large that my example, so definitely my problem its solve. Thanks a lot and... Cheers. FD

Comment: I'm glad I could help! Cheers Sly